# git remote branch checkout , files missing

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout items from a different git branch. I did fetch , then checkout and it said "up-to-date" , But where exactly that I see the 
"l02" ?

```
me@appliance (~/temp/mydir): ls
l01
me@appliance (~/temp/mydir): git fetch
git me@appliance (~/temp/mydir): git checkout l02
Already on 'l02'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/l02'.
me@appliance (~/temp/mydir): ls
l01
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are already at the branch you want, you need to use

```
$ git pull
```

This will apply a git fetch and a git merge

See [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Try git pull instead of Fetch (it merges the changes)